# How to bypass a method in Python..?

Tags: python

Here is the scenario.

I have a class(X) having a method xyz

I have to define a class(Y) which extends class(X) but should run 'xyz' of class Y  instead of 'xyz' of class X.

Here is the example :

```
Code in first.py :

class X():
    def xyz(self):
        -----

Code in second.py:

import first
class Y(X):
    def xyz(self):
        -----
```

Actually, my requirement is to call "Y.xyz()" whenever "X.xyz()" is called and I can't do modifications in 'first.py' but I can modify 'second.py'.

Could anyone please clarify this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Does another library already use `X` objects and you need to replace the `xyz` method *on that*? Or does your `Y` class do more than just override a method?

Comment: Just avoid defining `xyz()` in `Y`, and `X.xyz()` will be called. You might want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: In other words, are you looking for replacing *all* of `X` with `Y` in a third-party library, or is replacing *just the method* enough? Or are you looking to use `Y` in your own library?

Comment: @bavaza: other way around; the user wants `Y.xyz()` called when *instances* of `X` are used. I think.

Comment: You can convert the instance of class X into an instance of class Y then call instance.xyz() to make it call Y.xyz()

Comment: yes @Martijn Pieters. That is my exact requirement. I need to call Y.xyz() whenever X.xyz() is called..

Comment: @justhalf .It would be of great help if you provide an example. Unfortunately I can't edit first.py which holds Class X.

Comment: This question would be much improved with a more concrete explanation of why you need to do this. As of now it sounds like you have misunderstood some homework.

Comment: @LennartRegebro  - The main reason why I have to do this is , I don't have any write access to first.py but I should call Y.xyz() in second.py whenever X.xyz() is called in first.py

Comment: @Sobhan 1. No, that's what you *think you should do*, not **why you think you need to do it**. 2. That's not a concrete example with real code, it's an abstracted example. In short: **Show your code**.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - Unfortunately, I can't share the code here. But the scenario is same. Actuallt, first.py is implemented by some other project which has to be extended and the method is overridden in our second.py

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to monkeypatch.

Don't create a subclass, replace the `xyz` method directly on `X`:

```
from first import X

original_xyz = X.xyz

def new_xyz(self):
    original = original_xyz(self)
    return original + ' new information'

X.xyz = new_xyz
```

Replacing the whole class is possible too, but needs to be done *early* (before other modules have imported the class):

```
import first

first.X = Y
```

Comment: @Dave: I am reading the original question. The OP is **far from clear** what he wants to do. I ask specifically in the comments underneath the question what scenario out of 3 possible he is trying to solve.

Comment: @Dave: using subclasses, calling `Y().xyz()` is but one of the three.

Comment: I agree with @Dave that this sounds like a typical homework OO question. But it isn't a typical homework OO question. That leaves the possibility that it's either a real problem, or the OP misunderstood his homework. In either case we have to answer the actual question asked, and Martijn did just that.

Answer (score 0):

Converting is something like:

```
class X:
    def xyz(self):
        print 'X'

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self,x_instance):
        super(type(x_instance))

    def xyz(self):
        print 'Y'

def main():
    x_instance = X()
    x_instance.xyz()
    y_instance = Y(x_instance)
    y_instance.xyz()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Which will produce:

```
X
Y
```